# Explanation of conversion of Ascii Char to Binary in C

Tags: c, bit-manipulation, ascii

Can someone explain in a bit of detail how the following Char to Binary functions work in C?

Specifically how the bit shifting and logical and work on an iteration

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
void printCharAsBinary(char c) {
    int i;
    for(i = CHAR_BIT; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%d", ( unsigned int )( ( c & (1 << i) ) ? 1 : 0) );
    }
}

void printCharAsBinaryVer2(char c){
    int bit_index;
    for (bit_index = CHAR_BIT; bit_index >= 0; --bit_index)
    {
        int bit = ( unsigned int ) (c >> bit_index) & 1;
        printf("%d", bit);
    }
}
```

You can see them in action here if that helps:
http://code.geeksforgeeks.org/zC22WO

---

**Update based on answers:**

`F` is `70` in decimal

`70` is `01000110` in binary

With the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>
void printCharAsBinary(char c) {
    int i;
    for(i = CHAR_BIT; i >= 0; i--){
        printf("%d", ( unsigned int )( ( c & (1 << i) ) ? 1 : 0) );
    }
}
```

The iterations will be:

```
01000110 & 10000000 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
01000110 & 01000000 = 01000000  RESULT is > 0 so PRINT 1
01000110 & 00100000 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
01000110 & 00010000 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
01000110 & 00001000 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
01000110 & 00000100 = 00000100  RESULT is > 0 so PRINT 1
01000110 & 00000010 = 00000000  RESULT is > 0 so PRINT 1
01000110 & 00000001 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
```

With the following code:

```
void printCharAsBinaryVer2(char c){
    int bit_index;
    for (bit_index = CHAR_BIT; bit_index >= 0; --bit_index)
    {
        int bit = ( unsigned int ) (c >> bit_index) & 1;
        printf("%d", bit);
    }
}

00000000 & 00000001 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
00000001 & 00000001 = 00000001  RESULT is > 0 so PRINT 1
00000010 & 00000001 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
00000100 & 00000001 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
00001000 & 00000001 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
00010001 & 00000001 = 00000001  RESULT is > 0 so PRINT 1
00100011 & 00000001 = 00000001  RESULT is > 0 so PRINT 1
01000110 & 00000001 = 00000000  RESULT is 0   so PRINT 0
```

Comment: Not an answer, but understanding C operator precedence definitely helps. http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: No idea why this is getting voted down.  It is quite difficult to find a clear explanation of this concept

Comment: The second example shifts `c` `bit_index` bits to the right and then ands with `1`. If the bit at that position was set, this will result in `1` otherwise `0`. The first shifts `1` `i` bits to the left and ands with `c` This will result in a **non zero** value if the bit at position `i` was set, otherwise zero.

Comment: If you're going to edit the question to include that update, you'd probably want to show the iterations of the other loop because the operated upon values are different. At which point it probably deserves it's own answer

Comment: Doing any form of bitwise manipulation on `char` or signed integer types is dangerous practice. Isn't it nice to follow tutorials that teach you how to write buggy code?

Comment: Any reference for correct way @Lundin

Comment: @Robben_Ford_Fan_boy You can uncrapify the "tutorial" code with a few modifications: `void printCharAsBinary (uint8_t c) 
{
  for(size_t i=0; i<CHAR_BIT; i++)
  {
    printf("%d", c & (1u << (CHAR_BIT-i-1)) ? 1 : 0);
  }
}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Char has 8 bits in binary representation.
You are printing each bit as 1 or 0 in character representation like this:

You go through for loop and with counter you make logical shift to the left and then with bitwise AND you check if bit is set or not. If it is, you print 1, otherwise you print 0.

Lets say your number in binary is `01010101`

For loop iterations are:

1. `01010101 & 10000000 = 00000000` result is `0`, you print `0`
2. `01010101 & 01000000 = 01000000` result is `> 0`, you print `1`
3. `01010101 & 00100000 = 00000000` result is `0`, you print `0`
4. and so on.

After you print everything you get `01010101`.

Comment: Does Bitwise AND apply to one BIT or the entire byte?

Comment: I've updated my answer. Bitwise apply to bit by bit and not byte.

Comment: It applies to the whole of it, but the examples are only anding with a value that has only one bit set (either the value 1 in the second example or `1<<i` in the first) . The result being exactly zero or one bits set in the result

Comment: Yes, it applites to all, but bitwise AND clears bits in original byte where in mask is 0 and leaves bits where in mask is 1. So when you do `number & mask` you set bits to 0 where mask has zero bits and others are left unchanged. With this you can test if specific bit is set in original byte.

Comment: I'll make this the answer because for some reason the question keeps getting voted down to close, so it will probably be closed soon

Comment: Detail.  `char` has `CHAR_BIT` bits. See `<limits.h>`.   `CHAR_BIT` is very commonly 8, but may be more like 9,16,even 64 on not-so-common platforms.

Comment: More importantly, `char` has implementation-defined signedness. So for eaxmple `11010101 & 10000000`, the result is either 128 or -128, `> 0` or `< 0` and you can't portably know which. Simply _don't_ use `char` for storing numbers.

Comment: Lundin..if bit is set to 1, then it can be 127 or -128 (you wrote it wrong). This is still valid call and result is still true. No matter about signess here.

Comment: Your welcome to throw up the correct way to go from string to binary in c @Lundin or tilz0R

Comment: Your way is OK because bit is bit, signed or unsigned is just a way how to represent number when not in binary. Otherwise bits are still the same.

Comment: @tilz0R 0x80 = 128 if char is unsigned, or if char is 8 bit two's complement: -128.

Comment: Yes, my bad there to say that to you. But still, it doesn't matter in bit checking what is decimal value. Only if bit is set or not. In this case, it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

The type char can behave either as the type `signed char` or as the type `unsigned char`.

According to the C Standard (6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators)

> 4 ...If E1 has a signed type and nonnegative value, and E1×2E2 is
>   representable in the result type, then that is the resulting value;
>   **otherwise, the behavior is undeﬁned.**
>
> 5 ... If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, **the resulting
>   value is implementation-deﬁned**.

Thus in the both functions it would be better to cast the character to the type `unsigned char`.

The function can look like it is shown in this demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

void printCharAsBinary( char c )
{
    for ( int i = CHAR_BIT; i-- != 0; )
    {
        printf( "%u", ( unsigned char )c >> i & 1 );
    }
}

int main(void) 
{
    for ( char c = 'A'; c <= 'Z'; ++c )
    {
        printf( "%c: ", c );
        printCharAsBinary( c );
        putchar( '\n' );
    }       

    return 0;
}
```

Its output is

```
A: 01000001
B: 01000010
C: 01000011
D: 01000100
E: 01000101
F: 01000110
G: 01000111
H: 01001000
I: 01001001
J: 01001010
K: 01001011
L: 01001100
M: 01001101
N: 01001110
O: 01001111
P: 01010000
Q: 01010001
R: 01010010
S: 01010011
T: 01010100
U: 01010101
V: 01010110
W: 01010111
X: 01011000
Y: 01011001
Z: 01011010
```

That is the function sequentially shifts bits of the character starting from the most significant bit to the first position. The binary operator `&` sets all other bits except the first one of the resulting value to zero. Thus this expression `( unsigned char )c >> i & 1` extracts the target bit in the given character.

Comment: `( unsigned char )c >> i` assumes that the reader is aware of misc integer promotions though. The left operand will get promoted to `int` and you are actually doing shifts on a signed type, which isn't a brilliant idea. In this specific case it is safe just because of the unsigned cast. However `"%u"` is the incorrect format specifier, because the resulting type of the expression is `int`. To get rid of all such oddities, just cast to `unsigned int` instead.

Comment: @Lundin Casting the char to the type unsigned char allows to represent the character as unsigned value in the integer. Using format specifier %u is totally correct according to the C Standard because the outputted value is representable in the type unsigned int .

Comment: But an `unsigned char`, when used as operand in an expression such as  `c >>` will get integer promoted to type `int`. Suppose you change the code during maintenance to something like `~(unsigned char )c >>`. Now suddenly the signed operand is _negative_ despite the cast and you have an implementation-defined shift. It is always better to ensure that no implicit promotions are present in the first place.

Comment: @Lundin What is needed is that the value stored in the character would be promoted to an unsigned value.  And casting the character to the type unsigned char allows to achieve that. As for your imagined example then I usually understand what I am doing.:)